# Apache Virtual Host with Angular Fullstack (NodeJS) App 307 Redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, virtualhost, angular-fullstack

I have an Ubuntu server with multiple php applications running with Apache on port 9999.

At the same time, my NodeJS app on the same server runs on port 8080 and I use apache's virtual host to redirect requests from port 80 or 443 to my NodeJS app.

My virtual host looks like that:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com
   Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /ssl/example.com.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /ssl/example.com.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /ssl/intermediate.pem

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/marcel/www/example
        Options -Indexes

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        ProxyRequests on
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now all requests to example.com should be redirected to https://www.example.com. I have this .htaccess file.

```html
Options -MultiViews
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
  # Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On
  # RewriteBase /
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
</IfModule>
```

My Problem: When I go to http://example.com, I get redirected to https://example.com (without www, but ok) and I get a 307 redirect! I want 301 for SEO reasons. Same thing happens if I do www.example.com => it goes to https://www.example.com but also with 307 redirect.

Comment: I see a looping weird rule: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on ...... RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST} .....`. It seems that assumed a `https://` url-prefix and an `[OR]` flag for the 1st cond. Remove that excessive commented out text.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I removed the text. I don't see the loop though. And also, where does the 307 redirect come from, when that Rule says 301?

Comment: Enable a detailed log and search there by keyword 307: `LogLevel crit proxy:trace8 proxy_fcgi:trace8 rewrite:trace8`

Comment: I tried that (except proxy_fcgi because I don't have that module) and I could not find any 307 redirect :/